# How do I change the location of the Killfeed in the HUD?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I play Team Fortress 2 and I have a heads-up display installed. However, the kill feed and chat are in in the same spot. How can I change the killfeed position?

Comment: This is probably dependent on the specific HUD, could you provide more details?

Answer (score 3):

In your HUD folder there's a `hudlayout.res` file that's probably in the `scripts` folder. It contains all the details of where each HUD element should be, colors and other various preferences that you can change or play with.

You're looking for something called `HudChat` which should have associated xpos and ypos values. You can change these to modify the location where the chat panel shows up. Default values are the number of pixels from the left or top of the screen. Note that values such as `c90` and `r50` mean 90 pixels from the center and 50 pixels from the right, respectively.

I'm not entirely sure what the killfeed is called but you may be able to get by modifying the chat panel only. If you really need to change both, back up your file and try modifying other panels that *could* be the killfeed - there's at least one called `DeathNotice` that might be the right panel.

You can apply changes without restarting by running `hud_reloadscheme` in the console.